# Where to view historic counts of posts added/deleted?

Tags: support, statistics

I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba page. I see Roomba is some kind of bot that deletes the posts passing some criteria automatically.

I am curious to see the yearly counts for the following data from Stack Overflow for the past five years:

- Number of questions added
- Number of questions deleted by Roomba
- Number of questions deleted manually (community/moderation)
- Number of question deleted through any way (combination of above two)

Is this kind of data available somewhere?

Comment: bullet one and four are available in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/679995), I don't think we have delete reason in SEDE, you'll need a CM to answer that.

Comment: Maybe MSE has extra info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsede%5D+deleted

Comment: @rene: The link shows data from inception. Is there a way to convert it to yearly count for last five years. That said, there will be five records, one for each year.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, feel free to fork the query and apply your sql magic. I'm a bit short on time atm.